# Question on drawing 4 tickets form 7 tickets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A bag contains 7 tickets marked with the numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., 6 respectively. A ticket is drawn and replaced; find the chance that after 4 drawings the sum of the numbers drawn is 8.

Comment: Consider $$ \left[x^8\right]\left(\frac{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6}7\right)^4 =\frac1{2401}\left[x^8\right]\left(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\right)^4 $$

Comment: How many ways can you put $8$ indistinguishable balls into 4 boxes where each box will contain at most 6 balls?

Comment: Answer is 149/2401

Comment: Sorry I have wrongly calculated. I should have $\binom {11} {3} -16 = 149.$

Comment: @UtsavDesai: if you add your work to your question, people might upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can view $4$ drawings to be $4$ different boxes and the number on the ticket drawn at $i$-th drawing is the number of balls in the $i$-th box after the balls are thrown to the boxes where $1 \leq i \leq 4.$ Now since the numbers on the tickets are from $0,1, 2 , \cdots ,6$ so that means each box will contain at most $6$ balls.

So the number of ways to get $8$ as the sum of the tickets marked $0,1,2,.\cdots , 6$ in $4$ drawings is the number of ways $n$ to put $8$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ different boxes so that each box will contain at most $6$ balls.

Now let $n_7$ denote the number of ways to put $8$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ different boxes in which one of the boxes will contain $7$ balls and $n_8$ denote the number of ways to put $8$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ different boxes in which one of the boxes will contain $8$ balls. Then clearly $n_7 = 12$ and $n_8 = 4.$

Let $m$ be the number of ways to put $8$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ different boxes. Then $m = \binom {11} {3} = 165.$

Then $n = m - n_7 - n_8 = 165 - 12 - 4 = 149.$

So the required probability is $\frac {149} {7^4} = \frac {149} {2401}.$

Answer (score 0):

The tickets are drawn after replacement. Hence, the total number of possible ways of draws is 7 x 7x 7x 7 = 2401.

Now, for the number of ways in which the total adds up to 8 is the subset of these 2401 possible ways where the total is 8. For example, {3, 4, 0, 1} or {3, 2, 2, 1} adds to 8.

The total number of ways can either be counted by brute-force or recursively. Recursively, the number of ways to get a sum S with k drawings is: Sum over, each card value i from 0 to 6, number of ways for sum $(S-i)$ with $(k-1)$ drawings

$$ Count(S, k) = \sum_{i=0}^{6} Count(S-i, k-1) $$

The number of such draws is 149. 
$$ P(Sum = 8) = 149/2401 $$